# Windows server 2003 password issue

Tags: windows-server-2003

We have a server which running Windows Server 2003. I have a password problem with it.
It sometimes does not accept my password when I try to log in. When I restart the server, it strangly begins accepting my password that is same as I tried before.
My pasword has a **dot(.)** char and it has no non-ASCII or local chars. So what can the problem be?

Comment: Perhaps password caching is off and it cannot connect to an authoritative domain controller?

Comment: @ta.speot.is how can i check if it is on or off? It is a local server. It is the only machine in the network and has internet connection. So should it connect to an authoritative domain controller? By the way the login name is Administrator.